# iOS app does not show alert for permission of Addressbook access

Tags: ios, addressbook

I am working on an app which required to show contacts.

It is working fine on Xcode 6.2. But when I run this project on Xcode 7.2, then it is not even asking for Permission alert.

I write following method for get permission.

```
-(void)requestAddressBookAccess
{
    ContactsViewController * __weak weakSelf = self;

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(self.addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
                                             {
                                                 if (granted)
                                                 {
                                                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                         [weakSelf accessGrantedForAddressBook];

                                                     });
                                                 }
                                             });
}
```

It is always give `granted = false` and `error = nil`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Also, you are confusing your IDE with your target OS SDK's version. You're now probably compiling for iOS 9. [Most of the old API is depricated.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007099)

Comment: what does `ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()` return?, please note that `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` only works if authorization status is `ABAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined`, if it's `Denied` or `Restricted`, you need to tell the user about it and ask them to change the setting.

Comment: shameless plug: https://github.com/ishaq/ContactsImporter/blob/master/ContactsImporter/Libs/ContactsImporter.swift should help serve as a reference.

Comment: @JanGreve don't you love it when Apple deprecates an API and doesn't tell you what to use instead. /joy

Comment: AddressBook framework has been deprecated as a whole, Apple recommends using [Contacts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328) framework instead.

Comment: @ishaq yeah, big fan of that. I like it even better when they change behavior slightly - without documenting or renaming APIs.

Comment: My below answer is first show you alert authorization permission alert first.After that it shows you other details.My code works perfectly.I posted the answer here as I tried and got the output.

Comment: Tick and up vote my answer because it is very rare answer.Even if you look at stackoverflow only few question about this especially in iOS 9.From iOS 9 everyone has to start contacts framework.Other can get good solution through your well asked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 9 you have to use Contacts framework as Addressbook framework is depricated

```
-(void)addressbookAuthorizationUsingContacts
{
    //#import #import <Contacts/Contacts.h>

   // Request authorization to Address Book Using Contacts
   CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
   [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (granted == YES) {
        //keys with fetching properties
        NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
        NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
        NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
        } else {
            NSString *phone;
            NSString *fullName;
            NSString *firstName;
            NSString *lastName;
            UIImage *profileImage;
            NSMutableArray *contactNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            NSMutableArray *contactsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
                // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
                firstName = contact.givenName;
                lastName = contact.familyName;
                if (lastName == nil) {
                    fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
                }else if (firstName == nil){
                    fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
                }
                else{
                    fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
                }
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
                if (image != nil) {
                    profileImage = image;
                }else{
                    profileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"person-icon.png"];
                }
                for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers) {
                    phone = [label.value stringValue];
                    if ([phone length] > 0) {
                        [contactNumbersArray addObject:phone];
                    }
                }
                NSDictionary* personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: fullName,@"fullName",profileImage,@"userImage",phone,@"PhoneNumbers", nil];
                [contactsArray addObject:personDict];
                NSLog(@"The contactsArray are - %@",contactsArray);
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [tableViewContacts reloadData];
            });
        }
    }
}];
}
```

The Output results are

```
The contactsArray are - (
    {
    fullName = "John Appleseed";
},
    {
    fullName = "Kate Bell";
},
    {
    fullName = "Anna Haro";
},
    {
    fullName = "Daniel Higgins";
},
    {
    fullName = "David Taylor";
},
    {
    fullName = "Hank Zakroff";
}
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ABAuthorizationStatus status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus();

    if (status != kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized && status != kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {

    // tell user to enable contacts in privacy settings

    NSLog(@"You previously denied access: You must enable access to contacts in settings");

    return;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not a good idea. You need to explain what you are doing and why so that people understand what you are doing.